# sudo apt-get update returns warnings

Tags: apt, 18.10

Any idea about these warnings? I'm running the ubuntu 18.10 just upgraded at the latest patches.

```
Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease  
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                                                                   
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                          
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                         
Hit:5 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease                                                                  
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x cosmic InRelease                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done                                                
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as  
   repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease'
   doesn'thave the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

the warning is repeated several times for each package

Comment: As not too many people understand Italian and most online resources focus on the native English output messages, could you rerun your command with default locale and [edit] your question to replace the output? You get the default localization for just one single command by prefixing it with `LANG=C` - i.e. `LANG=C sudo apt-get update`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After google translate it seems like apt-get update complains about `main` not being found in http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dist/cosmic which is true. Do you get the same error for http://it.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease line as that repository does have `main` folder in the tree. For the broken repository path The packages.gz file seems to be located under http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/partner/binary-amd64/ so what I think you need to do to fix this is either enable **Canonical Partners ** in Ubuntu Software Sources window. (Ubuntu Software Centre > Edit > Software Sources) or edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add/uncomment

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner`

and comment out

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease`

================================

Comment: I added the

 `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner`

but there is no line containing `InRelease` into the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: Do you still get the warnings when you add the partner path? what do you get when you type in `sudo find . -type f -exec grep --exclude=*.conf.* -H archive.canonical {} \;` . Do you get any lines with InRelease or repeats?

Comment: Yes, the warnings are exactly the same and nothing seems changed

I rerun the cmd, and you can se the actual result in english in the original question.

While running the sudo find as you suggested, I discovered that it transforms a cosmic main' in a 'cosmic InRelease'.

Then, in the config file, as the `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease` was not present while the `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic main` was, I decided to try to comment out the latter.

Now the get update looks running without warnings, but I'm not sure if it really running fine ;-)

Comment: What you did was perfectly fine, That line was the was causing All your apt problems problems. , as it was not structured properly, thats all. `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner` will take care of canonical partnet packages. Once you earn your privilages on StackExchange, please try to return to this topic and upvote it for future readers.)